# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not returning new

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to [Mongoose's documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) the method `findOneAndUpdate` when passed the option of `new: true` should return the updated document with the new updates. But it seems that may have changed in 4.0?

> new: bool - if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false (changed in 4.0)

I have this block of code and the `console.log` **IS NOT** returning with the updated information. Neither is the callback.

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId(user._id) }, {
    $set: {
        files: view.getDocumentsOnly(files.files)
    }
}, { new: true }, function(err, userWithFiles) {
    console.log(userWithFiles);
    callback(userWithFiles.value);
});
```

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to return the updated document in Mongoose 4.0?

**Context:**

The function `view.getDocumentsOnly()` is just taking an array of Google Drive objects and returning an array of only objects with a document mimeType as opposed to a spreadsheet or folder. It is doing so synchronously and I can confirm that it is working. I can also confirm that the document is being updated in my MongoDB.

**Update:**

Here is the full code. The function parameter `user` is a mongo doc. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
getDriveFiles: function(user, callback) {
    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientID, clientSecret, redirectURI)

    oauth2Client.credentials = user.auth.token;

    google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client }).files.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,
    }, function(err, files) {
        if (!err) {
            Users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId(user._id) }, {
                $set: {
                    files: view.getDocumentsOnly(files.files)
                }
            }, { new: true }, function(err, userWithFiles) {
                console.log(userWithFiles);
                callback(userWithFiles.value);
            });
        }
    });
},
```

**User Model:**

Is referenced at the top in the same file as `getDriveFiles` above. It is referenced like this:

```
const db = mongoose.connect(env.DATABASE_URI).connection;
const Users = db.collection('users');
```

Here is the user model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        files: [],
        auth: {},
        ref: { type: String, default: id.generate() },
        stamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        in : { type: Boolean, default: false }
    });

    mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**console.log**

Here is what the `console.log` returns

```
{ value: 
   { _id: 57768c0b9712fe2d393dfcfb,
     ref: 'rk4MnbE8',
     auth: 
      { code: // removed,
        token: [Object] },
     in: true,
     stamp: 1467386891876 },
  lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
  ok: 1 }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I added all the code. The question isn't if this code works or not. The question is what did they change in Mongoose and how can I get the updated doc?

Comment: What you're doing by passing `{ new: true }` is correct with the latest Mongoose. Can you update your question to include the schema as well?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, added my user model. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Why do you pass `userWithFiles.value` to your callback? I don't see `value` defined in your schema. Also, is there a reason you don't define a schema for the `files` array elements?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, look the update I just provided above. Under console.log. I pass `userWithFiles.value` to the callback because that is what `findOneAndUpdate` returns.

Comment: Try like this `Users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:user._id},{........});`

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Weird. I just get the updated document in the callback. What you're seeing looks like what the native driver uses. That seems to indicate that `Users` isn't a mongoose model, but a native driver collection object. That would also explain why you're not seeing the updated document as the native driver uses `{returnOriginal: false}` instead of `{new: true}`.